# How can I get a list of all configurations for a Gradle project?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to get a list of all valid values for the `--configuration` flag of the [dependencyInsight](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:dependency_insight) or [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) gradle tasks. How would I go about doing this with Gradle 3.2.1?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
configurations.each { println it.name }
```

?

Comment: would this go in my main `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Cliabhach, yes for instance. You can also add it as a task.

Comment: Although...the outputs aren't being recognized by the dependencyInsight task. I'll update the question.

Comment: No wait, I got it. Turned out I needed to run `gradle app:dependencyInsight --dependency joda-time --configuration compile`, not `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency joda-time --configuration compile`.

Comment: Can this command be run from the command line?  I really don't need to put _litter_ into my build scripts.

Comment: @DavidGroomes Doesn't work anymore

Comment: Thanks @DarkNeuron I've deleted the comment (there's no edit option) since the approach I linked doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 57):

Try

```
gradle --console plain dependencies | fgrep ' - '
```

The dependencies task lists all configurations (along with their dependencies), and the fgrep will just show you the configuration names (along with a brief description of each).  It's not great, but doesn't require you to put stuff in your build script.

Comment: Ooh, interesting idea. What version of Gradle did you use?

Comment: @Cliabhach I don't remember what version I originally did this with, but I'm currently using 4.9 and it still works.  BTW, "--console plain" might improve the output (updating my answer to include that).

Comment: This only prints a small subest of configurations. 
e.g.
    archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
    default - Configuration for default artifacts.
    jacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
    jacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
    (*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

Answer (score 21):

With Gradle 5 it's very simple with the `--info` option. For example:

```
./gradlew projects --info
```

Now look in the `Configure project` section which lists all the configurations.

Comment: Huh, that seems to work well enough on Gradle 5.5.1. I take it you could use `--info` on any command that configures the project in question, and search for `Creating configuration` in the output.

Comment: Would you be ok adding a link to official (e.g. gradle.org) documentation on the `./gradlew projects` task?

Comment: @Cliabhach `--info` simply sets the logging level to `INFO`

Comment: @Cliabhach if you can find that documentation I'm happy to add it.

Comment: I'll see if I can! The fact that it's called 'projects' doesn't help much...

Comment: Can you add an example of what this should look like? I'm not sure I'm seeing anything useful.

Comment: I don't believe this provides useful output any more, probably as a result of Gradle getting smarter about resolvable vs consumable configurations (and not eagerly evaluating all configurations all the time).

Comment: Not sure what @stkent means, but this is what I'm using, `./gradlew projects --info | grep configuration | sed 's/Applying dependency management to configuration//'` -- It lists lines like `'testCompileClasspath' in project 'app'` which is useful enough for me. It seems like it's all the configurations.

Comment: @captain-man Which version of Gradle are you using? I'm using Gradle 6.6.1 here, and I can't seem to find ANY of those "Applying dependency management to configuration" lines any more (at least for a big/complex Gradle/Java project that I'm using).

Comment: @Hang actually it's possible this is from the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin. Gradle version is 7.3.1.

Comment: @captain-man Sure, will check out io.spring.dependency-management plugin.

Comment: Yeah this solution is outdated. Move on.

Answer (score 15):

```
gradle proj:resolvableConfigurations | grep "^Configuration"
```

And you probably want the `runtimeClasspath` configuration for `:dependencyInsight`.

#### Explanation:

There's actually a built-in task `resolvableConfigurations`
(since [Gradle 7.5](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/release-notes.html#new-features-and-usability-improvements)), so there's no need for having custom configuration-printing logic in your build scripts any more.

Its output is rather verbose and unwieldy as means of just figuring out the list of your configurations -- the `grep` extracts the name lines. Of course, you can go further and cut the word "Configuration" to get just the names:

```
gradle proj:resolvableConfigurations | grep "^Configuration" | sed "s/Configuration //g"
```

Comment: `./gradlew :resolvableConfigurations | grep "^Configuration"` seems to be working for me, with gradlew 8.4

Answer (score 14):

Add this to root project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ....
    }

    task printConfigurations {
        doLast {task ->
            println "Project Name: $project.name configurations:"
            configurations.each {
                println "    $it.name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for example:

```
$ ./gradlew -q :SubProjA:printConfigurations
Project Name: SubProjA configurations:
    -api
    -runtime
    annotationProcessor
    api
    apiDependenciesMetadata
    apiElements
    archives
    compile
    compileClasspath
    compileOnly
    compileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
    default
    implementation
    implementationDependenciesMetadata
    kotlinCompilerClasspath
    kotlinCompilerPluginClasspath
    kotlinKlibCommonizerClasspath
    kotlinNativeCompilerPluginClasspath
    kotlinScriptDef
    kotlinScriptDefExtensions
    runtime
    runtimeClasspath
    runtimeElements
    runtimeOnly
    runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
    sourceArtifacts
    testAnnotationProcessor
    testApi
    testApiDependenciesMetadata
    testCompile
    testCompileClasspath
    testCompileOnly
    testCompileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
    testImplementation
    testImplementationDependenciesMetadata
    testKotlinScriptDef
    testKotlinScriptDefExtensions
    testRuntime
    testRuntimeClasspath
    testRuntimeOnly
    testRuntimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
```

Comment: And is there any way to get for instance all of the "implementation" names? for instance if on my project I have implementation { dagger } could I get this "dagger" name?

Answer (score 7):

This is the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**) equivalent of other answers:

```kotlin
configurations.forEach(::println)
```

Put the above statement at the top of your build.gradle.kts file. It will print something like below whenever you run any task (like *build*):

```kotlin
configuration ':app:androidApis'
configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'
configuration ':app:androidTestAnnotationProcessor'
...
```

You can also create a dedicated task for this:

```kotlin
tasks.register("myConfigs") {
    doLast {
        configurations.forEach { println(it) }
    }
}
```

Run the task from the command line like this:

```bash
./gradlew myConfigs
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the configurations for the Java plugin:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

> compile(Deprecated) Compile time dependencies. Superseded by
> implementation.
>
> implementation extends compile Implementation only dependencies.
>
> compileOnly Compile time only dependencies, not used at runtime.
>
> compileClasspath extends compile, compileOnly, implementation Compile
> classpath, used when compiling source. Used by task compileJava.

> annotationProcessor Annotation processors used during compilation.
>
> runtime(Deprecated) extends compile Runtime dependencies. Superseded
> by runtimeOnly.
>
> runtimeOnly Runtime only dependencies.
>
> runtimeClasspath extends runtimeOnly, runtime, implementation Runtime
> classpath contains elements of the implementation, as well as runtime
> only elements.
>
> testCompile(Deprecated) extends compile Additional dependencies for
> compiling tests. Superseded by testImplementation.
>
> testImplementation extends testCompile, implementation Implementation
> only dependencies for tests.
>
> testCompileOnly Additional dependencies only for compiling tests, not
> used at runtime.
>
> testCompileClasspath extends testCompile, testCompileOnly,
> testImplementation Test compile classpath, used when compiling test
> sources. Used by task compileTestJava.
>
> testRuntime(Deprecated) extends runtime, testCompile Additional
> dependencies for running tests only. Superseded by testRuntimeOnly.
>
> testRuntimeOnly extends runtimeOnly Runtime only dependencies for
> running tests.
>
> testRuntimeClasspath extends testRuntimeOnly, testRuntime,
> testImplementation Runtime classpath for running tests. Used by task
> test.
>
> archives Artifacts (e.g. jars) produced by this project. Used by task
> uploadArchives.
>
> default extends runtimeClasspath The default configuration used by a
> project dependency on this project. Contains the artifacts and
> dependencies required by this project at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to do this on the command line:

```
gradle outgoingVariants
```

You'll have to do some parsing but you'll see something like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Variant yummyDebugRuntimeElements
--------------------------------------------------
Description = Runtime elements for debug
Capabilities
    - group:artifact:0.1 (default capability)
Attributes
    - com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr               = debug
    - com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:default.      = yummy
    - com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr                 = debug
    - com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr = Aar
    - org.gradle.usage                                             = java-runtime
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type                           = androidJvm


...
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. It can only show `*Elements` variants though, right?

Comment: I don't exactly recall, that project had a lot of variants and I just grabbed one.  This happened to be just one of the places the variant was visible.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Mike Hanafey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970140/430128) using Gradle Kotlin DSL, and adding another task that prints only resolvable configurations (useful for passing to the `--configuration` parameter of `dependencyInsight`).

```
allprojects {
  fun printConfigurations(filter: (Configuration) -> Boolean = { true }) {
    configurations.filter(filter).forEach {
      println("\t${it.name}")
    }
  }

  task("printConfigurations") {
    doLast {
      println("${project.name} configurations:")
      printConfigurations()
    }
  }
  task("printResolvableConfigurations") {
    doLast {
      println("${project.name} resolvable configurations:")
      printConfigurations { it.isCanBeResolved }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Just run these commands without the `--configuration` flag and the first lines of the output will be the list of available configurations

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about? I don't see a list of configurations in the output.

Comment: @DavidKennedy I'm unable to reproduce it with my current Gradle 4.10.2 but I recall that in the previous version I had if I had omitted the `--configuration` flag it would have listed all possible configurations